# SQL error whith INNER JOIN + LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to make a query where the data is in 4 tables:

```
TAFCBHISTPED = NUPED, DTEMIS

TAFGRPROD = CDGRPR, DSGRPR

TAFPROD = CDPROD, CDGRPR

TAFITHISTPED = NUPED, CDPROD, QTPED
```

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT
   TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED,
   TAFCBHISTPED.DTEMIS,
   TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR,
   TAFGRPROD.DSGRPR,
   TAFPROD.CDPROD,
   TAFPROD.CDGRPR,
   TAFITHISTPED.NUPED,
   TAFITHISTPED.CDPROD,
   TAFITHISTPED.QTPED
FROM
   dbo.TAFCBHISTPED -- table1
INNER 
JOIN dbo.TAFITHISTPED -- table2
ON TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED = TAFITHISTPED.NUPED
LEFT 
JOIN dbo.TAFPROD -- table3
  ON TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR = TAFPROD.CDGRPR
```

However I get the following error:

```
SQLState: 42000 Error Code: 4104 Message: 
[Microsoft] [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server] [SQL Server] 
The multipart identifier "TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR" can not be associated.
```

Comment: The main Stack Overflow site is English language only, try [pt.so]

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is an English based one so please edit your question to explain in English what is your issue. Otherwise we won’t be able to help you

Comment: Your query only references 3 tables - so you cannot include a column from the fourth one without joining to it or using a subquery in some fashion. Since you attempt to include columns from this fourth table in the select list, it seems you need to join to this table. How you do that depends on the relationships in your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have the relationship with the TAFGRPROD table

```
SELECT
   TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED,
   TAFCBHISTPED.DTEMIS,
   TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR,
   TAFGRPROD.DSGRPR,
   TAFPROD.CDPROD,
   TAFPROD.CDGRPR,
   TAFITHISTPED.NUPED,
   TAFITHISTPED.CDPROD,
   TAFITHISTPED.QTPED
FROM TAFCBHISTPED
INNER JOIN dbo.TAFITHISTPED ON 
TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED = TAFITHISTPED.NUPED

--CHECK THE REFERENCE FIELDS
LEFT JOIN dbo.TAFGRPROD ON 
    TAFCBHISTPED.CDGRPR = TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR

LEFT JOIN dbo.TAFPROD ON 
TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR = TAFPROD.CDGRPR
```

Answer (score 0):

To join tables, you need to have appropriate relationships. The diagram below explains what joins are available in SQL.
[image]

Table 2 and Table 3 have no relationship hence the join will fail. Useful tutorial for SQL join on this link. http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/